# Why cron tab not scheduling the cmd in linux

Tags: linux, cron

I create a cron by `crontab -e` and enter:

```
00 17 * * * mkdir /root/file1
```

at time 17:00 I don't find a file1 created by cron....

Please tell me what I do....

Comment: `crontab -e` edits the users crontab. Where you logged in as root user when executing `crontab -e`?

Answer (score 0):

Creating directory under `/root` requires roo privileges. You need to either (use `sudo` or confirm you are logged in as root.

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

or

```
# crontab -e
```

The command prompt of root is usually indicated by `#`. You can also check using `whoami`.